# apoc.load.jdbc check row property before create

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm using Apoc.load.jdbc to get data from Oracle Database and create row from it, here is the code:

```
call apoc.load.driver('oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver')
WITH "jdbc:oracle:thin:@10.82.14.170:1521/ORACLE" as url
CALL apoc.load.jdbc(url,"select * from Patients",[],{credentials:{user:'KCB',password:'123'}}) YIELD row
Create (p:Person) set p=row
return p
```

That code work fine but I want to check row property before create it. Such as:

```
If (row.ID!=p.ID) 
{
  set p=row
}
Else{Not set}
```

How can I do that with my code? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @TomažBratanič mentions in his answer, your desired conditional check makes no sense. That is, *unless* you also replace your `CREATE` clause.

Your query uses `CREATE` to *always* create a new `p` with no properties. So `row.ID <> p.ID` will *always* be true, and you'd always be executing the `SET` clause.

However, I *believe* your real intention is to avoid changing an existing `Person` node (and to avoid creating a duplicate `Person` node for the same person). So, below is a query that uses [MERGE](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/clauses/merge/) and [ON CREATE](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/clauses/merge/#query-merge-on-create-on-match) to do that. I assume that people have unique `ID` values.

```
CALL apoc.load.driver('oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver')
CALL apoc.load.jdbc(
  "jdbc:oracle:thin:@10.82.14.170:1521/ORACLE",
  "select * from Patients",[],{credentials:{user:'KCB',password:'123'}}
) YIELD row
MERGE (p:Person {ID: row.ID})
ON CREATE SET p = row
RETURN p
```

Also, you should consider creating an [index](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/administration/indexes-for-search-performance/) (or [uniqueness constraint](https://neo4j.com/docs/getting-started/current/cypher-intro/schema/#cypher-intro-schema-constraints)) on `:Person(ID)` to optimize the lookup of existing `Person` nodes.

Comment: Thank you! People have unique ID so your code works fine!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `CASE` statement to achieve this:

```
call apoc.load.driver('oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver')
WITH "jdbc:oracle:thin:@10.82.14.170:1521/ORACLE" as url
CALL apoc.load.jdbc(url,"select * from Patients",[],{credentials:{user:'KCB',password:'123'}}) YIELD row
Create (p:Person) set p = CASE WHEN row.ID <> p.id THEN row ELSE null END
return p
```

However, this statement does not make sense, because you always create a new Person, so the row.ID will never be the same as p.id.